# Velocity of two boats connected by long stick sailing trough river with varying water velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, kinematics

I am trying to reinvent curl definition. Simplest case is when vector field has only x component. So I will try to solve what is angular velocity of disk, that lies on the river surface. Disk lies on surface that has different velocities, so probably I will need to take surface integral. I need to find out how velocities of surface elements add together, so I need to consider simplest case. So I need to consider two differential elements of disk surface and see what is their velocity. It easier to solve problem for example when  motion is linear and then to try to solve it for rotation.

So I need to solve this problem.

> There are two boats with flat rectangular bottoms connected by long stick of length $d$. Boats move in one line that is parallel to river direction. They drift along a straight river with varying width, with the stick parallel to the river. The equation of water velocity in the river is $v(x)$ and the velocity of water under the boat is constant. What is the equation of boat velocity $u(x)$, and how to prove it?

I need proof more than answer.

Comment: You must be more precise. When you say the boats are connected by a stick, how is the stick oriented relative to the boats and the river? When you say the boats are 'sailing', do you mean drifting with the current?

Comment: I assume that boats and stick move parallel to river direction. By sailing I mean drifting.

Comment: But is the stick across the river, so that the boats are side by side, or is the stick aligned with the river so that one boat is ahead of the other?

Comment: One boat goes after other. Stick is parallel to river direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the position of one boat is $x$ and the speed of the water there is $v(x)$ and the other boat is at $x+d$ and the speed of water there is $v(x+d)$

Then the speed of the combined boat would be $$\frac{v(x)+v(x+d)}{2}\tag1$$

This average speed means that the forces on each boat cancel and it can continue at that speed.

For example if the boat in front wanted to drift at 12m/s and the one behind at 8m/s, if each drifted at 10m/s from (1), the one behind would be pulled back due to the 2m/s motion relative to the water.  The one in front would be pulled forward again due to the 2m/s relative motion, but those two forces would cancel.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is without a proof. I need proof more than answer. I am grasping that your answer is probably right, but I have no idea why it is right.